# Replace function not working

Tags: function, excel, replace, vba

What is wrong with this Replace function? Why does it not work?

```
 Sub test()
 MyString = "Armstrong has hamstring injury and his return is questionable"
 Injury = " Hamstring "
 NewString = Replace(MyString, Injury, "$InjType$", vbTextCompare)
 MsgBox (NewString)
 End Sub
```

Expected Answer : Armstrong has $InjType$ injury and his return is questionable

Answer Obtained : Armstrong has hamstring injury and his return is questionable

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the wrong place for the `vbTextCompare` parameter.

You can use

```
NewString = Replace(MyString, Injury, "$InjType$", compare:=vbTextCompare)
```

or

```
NewString = Replace(MyString, Injury, "$InjType$", , , vbTextCompare)
```

Comment: Oh!! Thank you so much. It works!! I was under the impression that since the optional parameters were optional anyway, they need not follow a particular order. Thanks again.